# PIVOT in oracle limitation

Tags: oracle, pivot

I would like to know if the limitaion on PIVOT list is still there in latest version of Oracle?

Working query

```
WITH DATA (A,DATE_FIELD,C,D) AS (
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01-JAN-2013'), 'tree',   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01-FEB-2013'), 'tree',   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('20-MAR-2013'), 'world',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('21-APR-2013'), 'tree',   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TO_DATE('21-JUN-2013'), 'tree',   30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01-JUL-2013'), 'world',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TO_DATE('30-JUL-2013'), 'world',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, TO_DATE('30-JUL-2013'), 'tree',   30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, TO_DATE('30-JUL-2013'), 'world',  30 FROM DUAL)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT   A, C, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR (DATE_FIELD, 'd')) AS DAY, SUM(D) D
  FROM DATA
  GROUP BY A, C, TO_CHAR (DATE_FIELD, 'd')
) PIVOT ( SUM(D) FOR (A,DAY) IN (
(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(1, 6),(1, 7),(1, 8),(1, 9),(1,10),
(1,11),(1,12),(1,13),(1,14),(1,15),(1,16),(1,17),(1,18),(1,19),(1,20),
(1,21),(1,22),(1,23),(1,24),(1,25),(1,26),(1,27),(1,28),(1,29),(1,30),
(1,31),(2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3),(2, 4),(2, 5),(2, 6),(2, 7),(2, 8),(2, 9),
(2,10),(2,11),(2,12),(2,13),(2,14),(2,15),(2,16),(2,17),(2,18),(2,19),
(2,20),(2,21),(2,22),(2,23),(2,24),(2,25),(2,26),(2,27),(2,28),(2,29),
(2,30),(2,31)
))
```

Not working query,

```
WITH DATA (A,DATE_FIELD,C,D) AS (
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01-JAN-2013'), 'tree',   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01-FEB-2013'), 'tree',   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('20-MAR-2013'), 'world',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('21-APR-2013'), 'tree',   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TO_DATE('21-JUN-2013'), 'tree',   30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01-JUL-2013'), 'world',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TO_DATE('30-JUL-2013'), 'world',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, TO_DATE('30-JUL-2013'), 'tree',   30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, TO_DATE('30-JUL-2013'), 'world',  30 FROM DUAL),
T1 AS (SELECT ROWNUM FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 2),
T2 AS (SELECT ROWNUM FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31),
T3 AS (SELECT * FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT   A, C, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR (DATE_FIELD, 'd')) AS DAY, SUM(D) D
  FROM DATA
  GROUP BY A, C, TO_CHAR (DATE_FIELD, 'd')
) PIVOT ( SUM(D) FOR (A,DAY) IN (SELECT * FROM T3))
```

Of course, this can work with PIVOT XML, or using a dynamic sql (which is what I'm actually using).

Comment: You can test it out yourself on DB fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/rv466QQn

Comment: The reason this cannot work is that when the optimizer parses the query, it must be able to get how many columns it returns. In your case it is impossible to do unless CBO executes 'select * from T3', and then it has no guarantee that this will return the same rows when the query is actually executed.

Comment: @gsalem I got your point, If youd like, post it as an answer with the link to docs or document id so I can mark it as Accepted